# Chrome Extension Development - Using local database and update it later

Tags: javascript, json, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Am a beginner in Chrome Extension development. I have done some useful projects, but never used database for my Chrome Extensions. So I decided to create a project for mom, which would make it easy for her to visit some websites.

Basically my local db (that I will include inside my Chrome Extension) would have a data format like this:

```
title | category | description | url

Google | Search Engine | Use this to search | http://www.google.com
Gmail | Email | Use this to view or send emails | http://www.gmail.com
Youtube | Videos | Use this to view videos or watch movies | http://www.youtube.com
......
```

Number of records would fall in the range of 200 to 500.

What am gonna do is, make my extension load a custom HOME page when a new Tab/Window is opened. And in that home page, there would be a search box. Where my mom can type some text like `Email` and it will filter out the items(from the above db) that matches this keyword.

Initially I was thinking about storing the above data in a JSON file and use it as the db. Because there's no insertion or updation of records via my Chrome Extension. Only querying and displaying is done. Also, I plan to write code to ping my webserver to check if there's any new db available, if so download and use it.

The problems that am facing is:

- if I go with using JSON file as my db, is there any better way to do the querying rather than iterating through the items and do a Javascript `indexOf()` on each item to check if it has the queried item?
- again, if I go with using JSON file as my db, how can I download the new updated JSON from server and save it replacing my local JSON file? I think `chrome.downloads` API doesn't allow this

Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Read JSON on install/update and write it into chrome.storage or IndexedDB, then use it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. If am gonna use `chrome.storage`, I should store the whole file in a single key like this `chrome.storage.local.set({ 'my_db': myJSONdata }, function() {  });` and later when needed, retrieve it and then iterate through it for finding the matching criteria and do the necessary stuff. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a possible approach.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. Do you think the iteration way of querying eats up resources, or it would be negligible for 200 to 500 records in my case? Google Chrome is already a resource hungry browser. Or you have any suggestion for performance in querying? Just asking so that I could finalize going forward with JSON and chrome.storage

Comment: Depends. For any performance-related concerns use devtools profiler and manual measurements of the elapsed time. If you don't like the results, switch to IndexedDB.

Comment: @wOxxOm awesome! Thanks for the inputs.